# boost::algorithm - splitting a string returns an extra token

Tags: c++, string, boost

Perhaps someone could tell me what is happening here?

My intention is to split an input string on braces: ie: either '**(**' or '**)**'.

For an input string of **"(well)hello(there)world"** I expect 4 tokens to be returned: *well; hello; there; world*.

As you can see from my exemplar app below I am getting 5 tokens back (The 1st is an empty string).

Is there any way to get this to return me **only the non-empty strings?**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <vector>
int main()
{
    std::string in = "(well)hello(there)world";

    std::vector<std::string> tokens;
    boost::split(tokens, in, boost::is_any_of("()"));

    for (auto s : tokens)
        std::cout << "\"" << s << "\"" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
$ a.out
""        <-- where is this token coming from?
"well"
"hello"
"there"
"world"
```

I have tried using `boost::algorithm::token_compress_on` but I get the same result.

Comment: Just curious, try removing the `(` before `well`. Probably the empty string string signifies nothing before first `(`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the first result returned is the empty set {} immediately preceding the first open parenthesis. The behavior is as expected.

If you don't want to use that result, simply test for an empty returned variable and discard it.

To test that this is the expected behavior, put a parenthesis at the end of the line and you will have another empty result at the end. :)

Comment: Funnily enough I have already done just this. I was hoping for something like a `skip_empty_tokens` argument or such like. I believe `boost::tokenizer` may have this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

this thread is kinda old but this is better solution `boost::token_compress_on`, add this after the delimeter in `boost::split`

Comment: No, `boost::token_compress_on` only merges adjacent empty tokens, but it will still generate an empty token at the beginning of a string.